# count collapsed consecutive results

Tags: t-sql

I'm looking to count a result set where items entered onto a system consecutively are collapsed as a single unit, and then the instances are counted from the resulting string / result set.

```
SELECT  items
FROM    table
WHERE   user = 'John Doe'
ORDER BY    date_entered_onto_system
```

i.e. over time, items entered onto the system in date order are PPP3333PP888P222PPPPPP

I want to collapse the string where items are consecutively entered onto the system, i.e P3P8P2P
and then count the resulting number of P, so answer here would = 4

Using T-SQL. many thanks in advance for help

Comment: Not clear. How does a single Item looks like? Why not just count rows with P?

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. And read the descriptions for the contradictory tags you've used. It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`.

Comment: I thought I was clear, but on re-reading I see where there might be confusion. "P, 3, 8, 2" are the individual items - I used a mixture of integers and characters in order that a mathematical solution wasn't put forward. It could easily be "car, bus, iPad, shoes" i.e. input over time might be "car, car, car, bus, bus, iPad, iPad, iPad, shoes, car, car". And I want to reduce to "car, bus, iPad, shoes, car" and then count instances of car

Comment: @MisterO What RDBMS are you on? (an example would be `sql-server-2014` as HABO mentioned)

Comment: SQL-server-2012

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume that you are on `SQL Server 2012` or later.

**Example Data:**

The following code is what I used to set up the example situation presented in the question.

```
create table #tmp_table (items char(1), date_entered_onto_system datetime)

insert into #tmp_table values ('P', '2016-11-08 12:01:00')
insert into #tmp_table values ('P', '2016-11-08 12:02:00')
insert into #tmp_table values ('P', '2016-11-08 12:03:00')
insert into #tmp_table values ('3', '2016-11-08 12:04:00')
insert into #tmp_table values ('3', '2016-11-08 12:05:00')
insert into #tmp_table values ('3', '2016-11-08 12:06:00')
insert into #tmp_table values ('3', '2016-11-08 12:07:00')
insert into #tmp_table values ('P', '2016-11-08 12:08:00')
insert into #tmp_table values ('P', '2016-11-08 12:09:00')
insert into #tmp_table values ('8', '2016-11-08 12:10:00')
insert into #tmp_table values ('8', '2016-11-08 12:11:00')
insert into #tmp_table values ('8', '2016-11-08 12:12:00')
insert into #tmp_table values ('P', '2016-11-08 12:13:00')
insert into #tmp_table values ('2', '2016-11-08 12:14:00')
insert into #tmp_table values ('P', '2016-11-08 12:15:00')
insert into #tmp_table values ('P', '2016-11-08 12:16:00')
insert into #tmp_table values ('P', '2016-11-08 12:17:00')
insert into #tmp_table values ('P', '2016-11-08 12:18:00')
insert into #tmp_table values ('P', '2016-11-08 12:19:00')
insert into #tmp_table values ('P', '2016-11-08 12:20:00')
```

**Answer:**

This query uses the `lag()` function and the `over` clause (links below) which are available on `SQL Server 2012` and later. This query compares the `items` value between a row, and the row before it (going in chronological order according to the `date_entered_onto_system` values). Evaluates to 1 if it should count, but 0 if not, and then it `sum`s up those values.

[Lag Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256.aspx)

[Over Clause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx)

```
select b.items
, sum(b.sum_val) as items_cnt
from (
    select a.items
    , case when a.items = lag(a.items, 1, NULL) over (order by a.date_entered_onto_system asc) then 0 else 1 end as sum_val
    from #tmp_table as a
    ) as b
group by b.items
```

**Results:**

This is the output of the example data.

```
items  items_cnt
  2        1
  3        1
  8        1
  P        4
```

Comment: Thanks @tarheel. I'm a noob when it comes to TSQL so thanks for the input. It's greatly appreciated.

Comment: @MisterO No problem, glad my assumption turned out to be true. If this solves your issue, make sure to click the check mark show this as the official answer. If it doesn't let me know, and we'll see what needs to be done.

Comment: @MisterO How did this turn out?

Comment: Hi all, using LAG works well on Reportwriter on Windows 2012. Only problem now is that the code is also wanted to be included on our data management system. Now we're okay on 2012 but... some of our clients use Windows 2008 so I'm probably going to have to rework it using CTEs - I think. Another area to build my knowledge in.